# What is a conservative/intersective function?

Tags: functions, set-theory

I can't find any information on what a conservative or intersective function is.
`For any set A, a function F from P(A) into [P(A) -> {T,F}] is conservative iff....`?  I don't mean to ask for the raw answer, but any general ideas on where I can look would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: It sounds to me like the part following the iff *is* the definition.

Comment: Well that part wasn't provided......if it was, I wouldn't need to be asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Edward L. Keenan, *Some Logical Properties of Natural Language Quantifiers*, in Joseph Almog and Paolo Leonardi, *The Philosophy of David Kaplan*:

Section 2.1.1, Def. 2 (with a slight change in notation):

> $D$ from $\wp(E)$ into $[\wp(E)\to X]$, $X$ any set, is *conservative* iff for all $A,B,B'\subseteq E$, $D(A)(B)=D(A)(B')$ whenever $A\cap B=A\cap B'$.

Prop. 1, which they say is the usual definition:

> A function $D$ from $\wp(E)$ to $[\wp(E)\to X]$ is conservative iff for all $A,B\subseteq E$, $DAB=DAA\cap B$.

(It appears that that last expression is short for $D(A)(B)=D(A)(A\cap B)$.)

Section 2.2.1, Def. 3:

> $D$ is *intersective* iff for all $A,A',B,B'$, $D(A)(B)=D(A')D(B')$ if $A\cap B=A'\cap B'$.

$D$ here is a *determiner*, or [*generalized quantifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_quantifier).

For more information, see the paper *The Semantics of Determiners* (pp. 11-13 for conservativity and intersectivity) and the brief survey *Quantifiers: Semantics* [here](http://www.linguistics.ucla.edu/people/keenan/keenan.htm). (Probably several other papers are relevant as well.)